# laravel regex validation utf-8 (Turkish letter)

Tags: regex, validation, laravel

I'm coding a web site with laravel. But I'm stuck in regex validation , cause my language looks like not supported with regex (probably I couldn't). There is a lot of way to check regex with PHP but I want to check rule with Laravel(4.2) validator. Here is my NOT WORKING code.

```
 ........
$name = Input::get('academy_name');
    $rules = array(
        'academy_name' =>  array('required','unique:academies,name,' . $name,'regex:/^([a-zA-Z0-9şŞıİçÇöÖüÜĞğ]+[\ \-]?)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/')
    );
    $validate = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    $messages = $validate->messages();
    if ($validate->fails()) {
.............
```

Like you see I want to use "üğÜĞişİŞçöÇÖı" letters. Thanks for all answer and idea.

Edit:
@henrik After your suggestion, I focus my research on PHP and finally found the answer. It's very simple, I just add /im to end of regex it's works like a charm. Here is my final validation: 
`$rules = array(
            'resource_name' => array('required', 'unique:resources,name,' . $name, 'regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZÇŞĞÜÖİçşğüöı]+[\ \-]?)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/im'),
            'category' => 'required',
            'file' => 'required',
            'class' => 'required'
        );`

Comment: Can you add some example data you want to be recognized by your expression?

Comment: I want all letter with turkish letters and only allowed only one dash consecutively. For example :
1-) "Hello-World-ÜĞİŞÇÖ-hi" 
2-) "Ağaç diktim dışarı"

Comment: then this `/^([0-9\p{Latin}]+[\ \-]?)+$/`should be enough to capture your examples https://regex101.com/r/sK5aY0/1 and https://regex101.com/r/zE8sI0/1

Comment: Like I say on below It's work on rubular.com etc. , but It's still can't work on Laravel :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Unicode character validation when trying to validate any language other than the English.

**For example**, the expression `/^[\u0041-\u007A]+$/` would validate any characters from 0041 to 007A, which corresponds to the Latin alphabet.

See [this chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) to identify your language and corresponding characters range.

Edit: as seen in comments below this has nothing to do with laravel

Comment: Are you using any third party packages to handle the Form validation, like for example Former? or are you only using laravels Form builder?

Comment: I'm just using Laravel Validation class [link] (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation) like basic usage...

Comment: Can you do a echo print_r($rules,true); right after you have built the $rules array. (Before: $validate = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);)

Comment: output is :  Array
(
    [academy_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => required
            [1] => unique:academies,name,Ağaç yaşken Eğilir
            [2] => regex:/^([0-9\p{Latin}]+[\ \-]?)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
        )

)

Comment: OK, and can you post your Form building code? everything from Form::open to Form::close

Comment: I didn't use Laravel Form, I used <form id="form" action="{{URL::to('academy')}}" data-redirect="{{URL::previous()}}"
                                  method="post">
after I catch URL and route to controller, it's above :/

Comment: Maybe the `Ağaç yaşken Eğilir`  part of `unique:academies,name,Ağaç yaşken Eğilir` messes with the validation ? Try to remove that.

Comment: Ağaç yaşken Eğilir
part is coming from view which is one of my input value 
like you see below. Is it really makes an error
$rules = array(
        'academy_name' =>  array('required','unique:academies,name,' . $name,'regex:/^([a-zA-Z0-9şŞıİçÇöÖüÜĞğ]+[\ \-]?)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/')
    );

Comment: Yes , I understand that your variable contains this string: `$name = Ağaç yaşken Eğilir` . But what I mean is this: Maybe The Laravel validator breaks when you send this string `Ağaç yaşken Eğilir` to it. So you should try to remove this part of the validation string just for testing purpose. In other words, check if this works:
`$rules = array(
        'academy_name' =>  array('required','unique:academies,name','regex:/^([0-9\p{Latin}]+[\ \-]?)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/')
    );`

Comment: I tested like you say but still not valid, also tested with one validation which is regex 'resource_name' => array('required','regex:/^([0-9\p{Latin}]+[\ \-]?)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/') like this still not valid :/

Comment: OK, can you try this then; `if (preg_match('/^([0-9\p{Latin}]+[\ \-]?)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', 'üğÜĞişİŞçöÇÖı') ) { echo "regex works. Something wrong with laravel"; } else { echo "regex doesnt work, something wrong with php."; }`

Comment: Looks like something wron with php :) output is 
regex doesnt work, something wrong with php.

Comment: Ok! What web server are you running?

Comment: XAMPP 5.6.3-0 on mac so answer is apache server.

Comment: Ok maybe you should finish this question and start a new one, since this has nothing to do with laravel, so you can get help from php/apache experts

Answer (score 0):

you could use `\p{L}` to allow any unicode character or `\p{Latin}` to allow any latin letter:

`/^([0-9\p{Latin}]+[\ \-]?)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/`

see http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: Yes looks like it's work on rubular but still can't work in laravel. I can't understand...